# What is the descriptor type used in case of constant buffers in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to create a descriptor set layout which has constant buffers (These constant buffers are used in PS and VS). I don't know what to use as descriptor type for the structure `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`. This is a basic question but I am new to Vulkan.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming You are talking about HLSL constant buffers, in the HLSL documentation we can read:

> Constant buffers reduce the bandwidth required to update shader constants by allowing shader constants to be grouped together and committed at the same time rather than making individual calls to commit each constant separately.

The closest equivalent in GLSL (and in Vulkan) for constant buffer is a uniform buffer. Thus You should specify `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER` during descriptor set layout creation.

If You need additional information about descriptor sets, You can read for example [6th part](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-6) of the *API without Secrets: Introduction to Vulkan* tutorial.